# Eslint prettier erroring on 'Replace `typeof·TYPE` with `(typeof·TYPE)`eslintprettier/prettier'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier

I have recently updated eslint and all of its plugins to the latest versions and now this is introduced, what rule is this? Can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but this rule seems to be coming from this release: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#232
but I am not sure if prettier allows disabling it. I ended up just changing the code to abide by this rule..

Comment: You cannot change this config option at time of writing.